How to work around RotateImmediately not being supported in boto3==1.28.57 when using AWS Secrets Manager with CDK?
How to work around RotateImmediately not being supported in boto3==1.28.57 when using AWS Secrets Manager with CDK?
Context:
I am using Python with the boto3 library version 1.28.57.
I need to rotate a secret in AWS Secrets Manager using CDK.
The version of the CDK library I am using does not support the RotateImmediately parameter.
I don't want the secret to be rotated immediately.
Then, my question is:
What's the best way to prevent the secret from being rotated immediately when using secrets_manager.rotate_secret with CDK, given the version of the libraries I'm using?
